# Valuechange Listener not reflecting the updated value - RenderResonse phase

Tags: jsf-2, valuechangelistener

I have two questions regarding the ValueChange listener and Renderresponse phase.

1. The valueChangelistener is not reflecting the value updated in the following code.

page bean code:

```
    public void changeListernMethod(ValueChangeEvent e) {
       setUpdatedCountry("You selected " + e.getNewValue().toString());
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();        
    }
```

added the line in valuechange method to skip to the render response phase , since the Valuechange method is called in PROCESS VALIDATION phase, and the UPDATE MODEL phase will overwrite any value set in the valuechange event method.

```
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
```

However, when any value is selected in the dropdown, the text box is not reflected with the selected value. I know this is something to do with the lifecycle, but couldnt figure out what it is.

1. During Render Phase, the values of the components are read from the ManagedPageBean or the Component tree(UIViewRoot) and displayed in the browser???

From BaluSc post  - http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html, I see the "The values to be shown are retrieved from the value binding getters in the backing bean" in RenderResponse which means the values are read from bean. If so how/when is the values updated to UIRootView to restore the view back for postback requests.

xhtml code below ...

```
 <h:selectOneMenu value="#{changeListenerBean.country}" onchange="submit()"            
valueChangeListener="#changeListenerBean.changeListernMethod}" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{changeListenerBean.countries}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:inputText value="#{changeListenerBean.updatedCountry}" />
```

Comment: Add the relevant xhtml code too. Before doing that make sure you have configured the web app properly and is atleast able to display some message.

Comment: Are you sending an ajax request or so?

Comment: @johny added the xhtml code.

Comment: @ BaluSc, No, not using any ajax request.